# Select each item without overlap time SQL

Tags: sql, overlap

```
Item    |   StartTime           |   EndTime
1       |   2015-08-15 03:00:00 |   2015-08-17 12:00:00
1       |   2015-08-15 07:00:00 |   2015-08-17 18:00:00
1       |   2015-08-18 03:00:00 |   2015-08-20 12:00:00
2       |   2015-08-15 03:00:00 |   2015-08-17 12:00:00
2       |   2015-08-15 07:00:00 |   2015-08-17 18:00:00
2       |   2015-08-19 04:00:00 |   2015-08-20 12:00:00
```

so, if i select non overlap objects, result should be:

```
1       |   2015-08-18 03:00:00 |   2015-08-20 12:00:00
2       |   2015-08-19 04:00:00 |   2015-08-20 12:00:00
```

Comment: 8-18 though 8-20 overlaps with 8-19 through 8-20. I'm confused.

Comment: @James one is `item1` other is `item2`

Comment: please include a tag with your rdbms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Explain

- first try to find a match where two ranges overlap `T1.StartTime <= T2.EndTime ...`
- but have to be a range for the same item `T1.item = T2.item`
- and have to be a different range `T1.StartTime <> T2.StartTime and T1.EndTime <> T2.EndTime`
- if can't find a match mean no overlap `T2.item IS NULL`

**[SqlFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/fdb3a/2)**

```
 SELECT T1.*
 FROM YourTable T1
 LEFT JOIN YourTable T2
   ON (T1.StartTime <= T2.EndTime)  and  (T1.EndTime >= T2.StartTime)
  and T1.item = T2.item
  and T1.StartTime <> T2.StartTime
  and T1.EndTime <> T2.EndTime
 WHERE 
     T2.item IS NULL
```

**OUTPUT**

```
| Item |                StartTime |                  EndTime |
|------|--------------------------|--------------------------|
|    1 | August, 18 2015 03:00:00 | August, 20 2015 12:00:00 |
|    2 | August, 19 2015 04:00:00 | August, 20 2015 12:00:00 |
```

Comment: you're unstopable. Tks <3